# Need to return a int from a method using long data types

Tags: java, casting

I need to return an int from a method, but the method uses longs declared earlier in the script.  Can anyone explain how I can use autoboxing to return an int from my method?  Any help at all is appreciated.

Comment: Please show the code of that method.

Comment: Long.intValue(); as descirbed in [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#intValue())

Comment: I'm not sure you understand the concept of `autoboxing`.  It is for example when you take a primitive `long` and set it equal to an Object `Long` example: `long i = 4L; Long j = i;` `autoboxing` occurs here...

Comment: Since you marked @andrewleach answer as correct we can assume you meant `casting` which is different than `autoboxing`.

Comment: It worked initally, but I ended up having to change it to
return Long.valueOf(int).methodName();
I did so to avoid data trunication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like this

```
return (int) someLong;
```

Comment: @Mortarman13 Be careful when doing this because if the `long` is to big it will not result in the same `integer` value. `long` is a larger data type than `int`...